# Migrating from OpenTracing to OpenTelemetry

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry, java-17

So I was using Open Tracing to trace calls to the microservice. I used to do it the following way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.31.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jaegertracing</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaeger-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.31.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then add following bean:

```
@Bean
public Tracer initTracer() {
    Configuration.SamplerConfiguration samplerConfig = new Configuration.SamplerConfiguration().withType("const").withParam(1);
    Configuration.ReporterConfiguration reporterConfig = Configuration.ReporterConfiguration.fromEnv().withLogSpans(true);
    return Configuration.fromEnv("my-service").withSampler(samplerConfig).withReporter(reporterConfig).getTracer();
}
```

When running I usually get these `span reported` logs whenever an external request is given to the application.

But with open telemetry I cannot simply do this anymore. What is the correct way to simulate  the behaviour?